# Connect to SQL Server from a local LAN computer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 - R2 database - database - configured to receive connection from internet.

The computers from LAN (Local clients) can connect to the database with its local IP address 192.168.100.200.

The computers from internet can connect to the db with its forwarded port through the public IP address,  123.128.28.184.

Due to some coding circumstance, I can only connect to the database through public address when I'm in LAN. So I need the local clients to connect to the public IP address 123.128.28.184, but this seems not possible.

Network configuration is shown as in 1st picture.

The [?] connection returns error in 2nd picture.

How can I use my local client to connect to my database server through the public address?

[image: Network configuration]

[image: The ? return this]

Comment: Have you enabled outgoing port 1433 on your clients and on your router (usually it is enabled by default)

Comment: Also, to narrow down the issue, connect to server `tcp:123.128.28,184`. This forces TCP (port 1433 by default). What exactly is the issue with connecting with a local address? There are many ways to alias local addresses. You can use a SQL Server alias or the `hosts` file

Comment: The connection error message mentions the Named Pipes Provider. On the problem workstation try opening SQL Server Configuration Manager and in the 32-bit and 64-bit Client Protocols enable the TCP/IP protocol, also make sure that its Order is lower than the Named Pipes protocol (i.e.: it's a higher priority and should be tried first).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, AlwaysLearning

Yes, I have fowarded port 1433 to inbound connect from my router, along with allowing everything inbound / outbound from firewall. Configured the SQL Server Client Protocols too. Aside from the Local to Public connect, everything else worked fine : Local computer to local ip database worked, internet (a different network) to public database ip worked. Only the part where Local computer connect to public database IP address not work, as I shown in the network picture up in my question.

Comment: I'm sorry the public IP in question is a fake one. I think I cannot post my company's real database IP here..

Comment: But why do you even need local to public?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that's more of a programming circumstance. Actually, I'm coding a program to observe data from the database on an android mobilephone. So, because I'm not always in the workshop, I think I will have to code the program to connect to the database from internet using public ip.But with public ip comes the above problem : I cannot connect to the database while i'm using the workshop network.

Comment: So i'm looking for a way to connect by reconfig the modem with anyway possible, either config a static route or using a vpn, or whatever else way possible. I thought about getting the IP from the phone and check if it's local or public, but as I research, I found that getting IP address from android phone is not an easy task,. what with those permission and all.

Comment: To find the IP address of anything, including an android phone, go to google and type whatsmyip. This is the address seen from the internet, not the local IP

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually, I'm talking about getting the IP address from inside the program i'm developing. It's not like you can just program it to casually open a browser, go to a specific address and retrieve data from it. That behavior would be counted as a malware / adware and can potentially harm your phone, so there's the permission i talked about.

Comment: Actually that's how web services work. For example you `GET http://myexternalip.com/raw`. You don't use a browser, you make a HTTP call. Although I'm not exactly sure how this is managed on phones. Anyway that isn't required to do what you want to do here